# The uniform convergence of a power series on a connected open set

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

The problem is to prove that 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n $$ uniformly converges on a connected open set $D$ if and only if it uniformly converges on $\overline{D}$.

The sufficiency is trivial.Since it uniformly converges on $\overline{D}$, it must uniformly converges on $D$. But the necessity seems hard to prove.

Please show me how to prove the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $N$ so that any two partial sums with at least $N$ terms differ by at most $\varepsilon$ on $D$. Note that partial sums are polynomials, and so continuous on all of $\mathbb{C}$. I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: Thank you.Sometimes I just get stupid and donˊt know what to do.

Comment: It happens to us all, no worry.

Comment: A mathematician was presenting a proof, and said,"Now the following point is obvious....", and wrote it on the board, and said,"because...", and stopped, scratched his head, said "Excuse me" ,and left. He returned 20 minutes later with a sheaf of notes and said,"I was right.It IS obvious."

Comment: @user254665 Somehow I couldnˊt understand your story.

Comment: It's a standard joke, told by undergraduates since the dawn of civilization. It doesn't seem particularly relevant here, though. Except perhaps for the point of sometimes missing the obvious.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen It seems that I am not a humorous person.